# nil coalescing inside dictionary index using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsdictionary, coalescing

Im trying to assign a value to dictionary key with optional value from textfield `textFieldOne.text!` and `textFieldTwo.text!`, but Xcode throws build error.

```
let variable = [
        "keyOne": textFieldOne.text ?? "",
        "keyTwo": textFieldTwo.text ?? ""
] as [String : Any]
```

Build Failed as **The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to as default of `text` property is ""

```
let variable = [
    "keyOne": textFieldOne.text!,
    "keyTwo": textFieldTwo.text!
 ]
```

Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text

Comment: Thanks! what if it has a variable initialised as `var variableName : String!` and inside dictionary `"keyThree": variableName` . Can I use `"keyThree": variableName ?? ""`

Comment: @DoubtAN Why not `var variableName = ""`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `Dictionary` like,

```
var variable = [String:Any]()
variable["keyOne"] = textFieldOne.text
variable["keyTwo"] = textFieldTwo.text
```